# Excited States of Helium

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

The question asks: The two electrons of Helium are found in the antisymmetrized version of $\Psi_{He} = \chi(r_{1})\Theta(r_{2})$ where $\chi(r) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt5} \psi_{100} + \frac{2}{\sqrt5}(1+i) \psi_{211})|\uparrow>$ and $\Theta(r)$ = $\psi_{100}|\uparrow>$.

a) Write the normalized antisymmetric form of the above wavefunction

b)Using the above wavefunction calculate the following expectation values: E = $<\Psi|\hat{H}|\Psi>$,$<\Psi|\hat{L^{2}}|\Psi>$, and $<\Psi|\hat{L_{x}}|\Psi>$.

**The Attempt**

a) I just antisymmetrized the wave function and said that $\Psi_{He} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\chi(r_1)\Theta(r_2) -\chi(r_2)\Theta(r_1)) $

I think i did this right, but it's possible that I made a mistake... I'm more concerned about part b)

b) For B I started with trying to solve for E by doing:

E = $\frac{1}{2}(<\chi(1)|<\Theta(2)| - <\chi(2)|<\Theta(1)|)(H_1+H_2)(|\chi(1)>|\Theta(2)>-|\chi(2)>|\Theta(1)>)$

Which I reduced eventually to :
$\frac{1}{2}(<\chi(1)|(H_1)|\chi(1)> + <\Theta(2)|H_2|\Theta(2)> - <\chi(1)|H_1|\Theta(1)> - <\Theta(1)|(H1)|\chi(1)>  $

$-<\Theta(2)|H_2|\chi_2> - <\chi_2|H_2|\Theta_2>+<\chi(2)|(H_1)|\chi(2)> + <\Theta(1)|H_2|\Theta(1)>$

but somehow i keep getting imaginary values in my energy which doesn't qualitatively make sense to me? Any advice?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: didn't know that was a thing! Thanks Ben!

Comment: Could you detail the last equation until you get the imaginary values as you mentioned?